# Ajax Call and return error in asp.net mvc3

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

i call an action controller in my view and when i set break point and watch the act of ajax function it work correctly on code behind but when back to function it not run '**success:function**' and return error

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/GetListContents",
        data: { _PageID: PageID, _LangID: LangID, _BoxTypeID: 6, _ListTypeID: 8, _Count: CurPageIndex },
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (html) {
            $("#dynamicBody").html(html);
            $("#dynamicFooter").html("Hello");
        },
        error: function (xhRequest, ErrorText, thrownError) {
            $("#dynamicBody").html(xhRequest.status);
            $("#dynamicBody").html(ErrorText);
        }
    });
```

the **GetListContents** work on code behind but the result is error
tnx for advance
and sorry for poor english
**Update**
this is my action controller code

```
[HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult GetListContents(int _PageID, int _LangID, int _BoxTypeID, int _ListTypeID, int _Count)
    {
        dynamic cOut = GetListContent(_PageID, _LangID, _BoxTypeID, _ListTypeID, _Count);
        return PartialView("DynamicPagingBoxInfo",null);
    }

    public dynamic GetListContent(int _PageID, int _LangID, int _BoxTypeID, int _ListTypeID, int _Count)
    {
        List<ipMedia_PageContentsCache> PageContent = new List<ipMedia_PageContentsCache>();
        ListPageDataProvider.GetDynamicBoxContent(ref PageContent, _PageID, _LangID,_Count * 10);
        ViewBag.PageListContents = PageContent;
        ViewBag.CurPageIndex = _Count;
        return PageContent;
    }
```

Update ||
more explain :
my partial view use viewbag to render page and get data from code behind
this partial view for first time that run on page request work fine but when i want render it with ajax,ajax function return error!
my view bag has same structure in first time and in ajax call

Comment: Can you show us the code for Action in Controller ?

Comment: is your partial page expecting a model? is it strongly typed? you are passing null to it may be exception is thrown in the partial page while rendering

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using models and taking advantage of model binding? Using this standard technique you would need to write very little JavaScript. Additionally your controller would be less verbose.

Comment: yes one variable is null and when partial view cant convert it to requested data and got error..  
tnx Every Body

Answer (score 1):

You need to send back the actual html from your controller.  Take a look at `RenderPartial`.  I have used the following code to perform this function in the past (placed on a base controller that my controllers inherit from):

```
    protected string RenderPartialView(string viewName, object model)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        {
            viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
        }

        ViewData.Model = model;

        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);

            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: render partial in code behind?  i cant use it
or use in view? can you say more?

Comment: You pass back the string from your controller action.  I usually pass back json containing a `success` property and a `view` property with `message` when there is an error.  The `view` would then contain the rendered html.

Comment: with your answer i found that i forgot to send a data to my partial view and when it request that variable its null and got error,tnx

Answer (score 0):

may be an error is in line

```
url: "/GetListContents",
```

try use `url: '@Url.Action('GetListContents','YourControllerName'),` instead

Comment: no,when i set break point on function body in code behind the function run correctly and no exception throw!